# ActivityIndicator Doesn't Work if it Doesn't Start Visible

Tags: maui

I have a project that was working with MAUI RC1, but has issues now that I've upgraded to GA.  One of them is the ActivityIndicator - after upgrading it didn't show up at all on either iOS or Android.  I tried removing it, redploying, adding it back in, and redeploying again.  That fixed it for iOS.

On Android it still doesn't work, and I finally found that I had to set it IsVisible to be True in the Xaml so it starts out visible, otherwise the code behind that toggles IsVisible and IsRunning doesn't work.  Here's an example of the Xaml I added to a new project to demonstrate:

```
<Button 
x:Name="SpinOn"
Text="Spin On"
Clicked="SpinOnClicked"
HorizontalOptions="Center" />

<Button 
x:Name="SpinOff"
Text="Spin Off"
Clicked="SpinOffClicked"
HorizontalOptions="Center" />

<ActivityIndicator IsVisible="True" IsRunning="True" x:Name="TheSpinner" />
```

Here's the code to toggle it:

```
    private void SpinOnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TheSpinner.IsRunning = true;
        TheSpinner.IsVisible = true;
    }

    private void SpinOffClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TheSpinner.IsRunning = false;
        TheSpinner.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

If I set the IsVisible property to "False", then the buttons to toggle it don't work.  But if it starts out True as shown above, it does work.  In RC1 my app had IsVisible="False" and it worked there (and still does today on iOS).

Is this now expected behavior, or something to fix?  I don't want to have my app launch with it showing and spinning if possible.

Comment: I test your code on the VS 2022 17.2 preview 6.0 and it worked well but when I update to the 17.3 preview 2.0, I meet the same problem, so it seems a new bug in the maui GA, you can report a issue on the [github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: An issue targeting this bug already exists: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8044

Comment: Thank you so much, Steve. I have been struggling with the acitivty indicator using the IsBusy boolean, and the only solution I had that worked was, per your advice, to not set the value to False on IsVisible in the Xaml by default. Oddly enough, This wasnt an issue with my app on Windows or iOS, just Android.